# styled-components, Referring to other components and use its props?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How do I make this work?

`img` is passed as `<Child />`'s props, and I want to change the child's background-image when `<Parent />` is hovered

```html
<Parent>
  <Child img={'path/to/img.png'}/>
</Parent>
```

```js
const Child = styled.div`

`;

const Parent = styled.div`
  &:hover {
    ${Child} {
      background-image: url(${props => props.img});
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: I guess it's because the 'img' is passed to Child instead of Parent, but you're accessing it inside Parent.

Comment: As haopeng said, in that case `props` contains the props of `Parent` Component, not the props of `Child` component. Do you need to achieve your goal with `styled-component` only, or you can use some workaround using JS?
EDIT: it would be useful to know if `Child` will always be the only child of `Parent`; if so, I can show you a solution using only styled-component

Answer (score 2):

Hope this can help you!

```
   &:hover ${Child}{
      background-image: url(${props => props.image && css`${props.image}`});
   }
```

Here is the working example https://codepen.io/hardik-chaudhary/pen/rKEKWG

---

> UPDATED CODE

Use hover code in the child instead of parent. And everything just works fine. I also updated the code in the pen(https://codepen.io/hardik-chaudhary/pen/rKEKWG).

```
const Child = styled.div`
   ${Parent}:hover & {
      background-image: url(${props => props.image && css`${props.image}`});
  }
`;
```

Comment: it works because you pass `image` to `<Button />`, what if I want `image` pass to `<Child />`, I don't want `<Child />` use its parent's props, it makes the code ugly.

Comment: I updated the code in the given pen. You can pass prop from child and can change the background on hover.

Answer (score 1):

So, I did manage to salve part of the problem (maybe what's left it's not important in your case, let me know).

First the fiddle, then the explanations:

```js
const img1 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2047905/pexels-photo-2047905.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=apple-device-art-colorful-2047905.jpg&fm=jpg";
const img2 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2027104/pexels-photo-2027104.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940";
const img3 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2029478/pexels-photo-2029478.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940";

window.styled = window.styled.default;

function changeBG(props) {
    if (Array.isArray(props.children)) {   
        let a;
        props.children.forEach(el => {
            if (el.type.styledComponentId === Child.styledComponentId) {
                a = el.props.bgImg;
            }
        });
        return a;
    } else {
        return (props.children.type.styledComponentId === Child.styledComponentId)
            ? props.children.props.bgImg
            : ""
    }    
}

const Child = styled.div`
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-image: url("${img2}");
    background-size: contain;
`;

const Parent = styled.div`
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    &:hover {
        ${Child} {            
            background-image: url("${props => changeBG(props)}");
        }
    }
`;

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Parent>
                <Child bgImg={img1} />
                <Child bgImg={img3} />
            </Parent>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
const img1 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2047905/pexels-photo-2047905.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=apple-device-art-colorful-2047905.jpg&fm=jpg";
const img2 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2027104/pexels-photo-2027104.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940";
const img3 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2029478/pexels-photo-2029478.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940";

window.styled = window.styled.default;

function changeBG(props) {
    console.log(props.children);
    if (Array.isArray(props.children)) {   
        let a;
        props.children.forEach(el => {
            if (el.type.styledComponentId === Child.styledComponentId) {
                a = el.props.bgImg;
            }
        });
        return a;
    } else {
        return (props.children.type.styledComponentId === Child.styledComponentId)
            ? props.children.props.bgImg
            : ""
    }    
}

const Child = styled.div`
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-image: url("${img2}");
    background-size: contain;
`;

const Parent = styled.div`
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    &:hover {
        ${Child} {            
            background-image: url("${props => changeBG(props)}");
        }
    }
`;

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Parent>
                <Child bgImg={img1} />
                <Child bgImg={img3} />
            </Parent>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/3.4.10/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Basically, the `Parent` styled-component acts like you wrote, expect that it runs a function called `changeBG`. In that, checking `el.type.styledComponentId === Child.styledComponentId` I check that the child is of type `Child`: if so, we can use the `props.bgImg`.

Though, there may be some problem if `Parent` Component has children that are not `Child` type.. And, if there are more than one `Child` Component as child of `Parent`, I still haven't been able to display different background image on hover.. But, I ask, is this needed? I can try and find a workaround for that too.